# How to access nifi which is running on other machine

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I'm running nifi on linux image (cloud instance) and now want to access it from my system and use the UI to configure the processors and flow based on my requirement. i.e., All I want is, how we are able to use UI on localhost when running nifi on the same system, similarly want to access the nifi which is running on other system and use it on my machine.

So, I simply running the nifi on remote server and just using it ip address instead of local host but it's not working? How can I access it? Are any properties needed to be changed or configured in properties files ????

Answer (score 1):

do you have ssh access to the cloud instance? Then you could try port forwarding

```
ssh -L <custom-local-port>:localhost:<nifi-port> <cloud-ip>
```

This will port forward local nifi port on your cloud host to the specified local port.

https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling/example